# IMAP email account read issue

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a Microsoft exchange account and a few imap email addresses used by multiple users. This works well as the users can all see the replies in the conversations with clients.

The issue I have is that when a user reads an email it is marked as read and can be missed. Is there a way to see the replies and leave it unread in other clients?

I would use Pop but the issue is not being able to see the replies, which would be a bigger issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you want it to keep track of ‘‘read’’ status per message *per user* within the same mailbox?

Comment: I want to be able to read a message and reply and then have the message to appear unread on the other clients. I realise this is not normal IMAP behaviour but hopefully I can achieve it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the RFC 3501 an IMAP elements can have only one flag for read (see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501)). So your approach might not work here.

So what you need is a kind of 3rd party software. Out of the blue without knowing your require the opensource application OTRS might work. OTRS might fetch the emails from a mailbox and the users can work with them. The emails will become tickets and its mostly clear for the user to understand who proceeded with the email and which are still open.